# Why are transparent pixels on quads only rendering correctly from one angle?

Tags: vulkan

Here is a row of textures/quads, with **the closest image to the camera created last**:

[Screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UEVet.png)

This works perfectly! However, as soon as you view the textures from an angle where **the closest image to the camera is created first**, the transparent pixels only pick up the background color:

[Screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XwZom.png)

What's confusing though is that the pixels from this angle will pick up "real" 3D models correctly, while completely ignoring the quads between them, regardless of which order the 3D model was created in:

[Screenshot 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AWGLB.png)

**Code Dump**

To be honest I'm not sure which pieces of the code to post here, whether this issue is being caused by a wrongly configured depth stencil or something else entirely. If there's anything pertinent missing then please let me know and I'll update the question.

**createDepthStencil()**

```
// Get Depth Format
std::array<VkFormat, 5> depthFormats = {
    VK_FORMAT_D32_SFLOAT_S8_UINT,
    VK_FORMAT_D32_SFLOAT,
    VK_FORMAT_D24_UNORM_S8_UINT,
    VK_FORMAT_D16_UNORM_S8_UINT,
    VK_FORMAT_D16_UNORM
};

for (auto& format : depthFormats)
{
    VkFormatProperties formatProps;
    vkGetPhysicalDeviceFormatProperties(vulkanDevice.physicalDevice, format, &formatProps);
    // Format must support depth stencil attachment for optimal tiling
    if (formatProps.optimalTilingFeatures & VK_FORMAT_FEATURE_DEPTH_STENCIL_ATTACHMENT_BIT)
    {
        depthFormat = format;
        break;
    }
}

// Assert that we have a depth format to use
assert(depthFormat != VK_FORMAT_UNDEFINED);

VkImageCreateInfo depthImageInfo = {};
depthImageInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_IMAGE_CREATE_INFO;
depthImageInfo.pNext = nullptr;
depthImageInfo.imageType = VK_IMAGE_TYPE_2D;
depthImageInfo.format = depthFormat;
depthImageInfo.extent = { vulkanSwapChain.extent.width, vulkanSwapChain.extent.height, 1 };
depthImageInfo.mipLevels = 1;
depthImageInfo.arrayLayers = 1;
depthImageInfo.samples = VK_SAMPLE_COUNT_1_BIT;
depthImageInfo.tiling = VK_IMAGE_TILING_OPTIMAL;
depthImageInfo.usage = VK_IMAGE_USAGE_DEPTH_STENCIL_ATTACHMENT_BIT;
depthImageInfo.sharingMode = VK_SHARING_MODE_EXCLUSIVE;
depthImageInfo.flags = 0;

VmaAllocationCreateInfo depthImageAllocCreateInfo = {};
depthImageAllocCreateInfo.usage = VMA_MEMORY_USAGE_GPU_ONLY;

// Create Depth Stencil Image
if (vmaCreateImage(vulkanMemory, &depthImageInfo, &depthImageAllocCreateInfo, &depthImage, &depthImageAllocation, &depthImageAllocationInfo) != VK_SUCCESS) {
    throw std::runtime_error("Failed to create Depth Stencil Image!");
}

VkImageViewCreateInfo depthStencilView = {};
depthStencilView.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_IMAGE_VIEW_CREATE_INFO;
depthStencilView.pNext = nullptr;
depthStencilView.viewType = VK_IMAGE_VIEW_TYPE_2D;
depthStencilView.image = depthImage;
depthStencilView.format = depthFormat;
depthStencilView.flags = 0;
depthStencilView.subresourceRange = {};
depthStencilView.subresourceRange.aspectMask = VK_IMAGE_ASPECT_DEPTH_BIT | VK_IMAGE_ASPECT_STENCIL_BIT;
depthStencilView.subresourceRange.baseMipLevel = 0;
depthStencilView.subresourceRange.levelCount = 1;
depthStencilView.subresourceRange.baseArrayLayer = 0;
depthStencilView.subresourceRange.layerCount = 1;

// Create Depth Stencil Image View
if (vkCreateImageView(vulkanDevice.logicalDevice, &depthStencilView, nullptr, &depthImageView) != VK_SUCCESS) {
    throw std::runtime_error("Failed to create Depth Stencil Image View!");
}
```

**createRenderPasses()**

```
std::array<VkAttachmentDescription, 2> attachments = {};

...

// Depth attachment
attachments[1].format = depthFormat;
attachments[1].samples = VK_SAMPLE_COUNT_1_BIT;
attachments[1].loadOp = VK_ATTACHMENT_LOAD_OP_CLEAR;
attachments[1].storeOp = VK_ATTACHMENT_STORE_OP_DONT_CARE;
attachments[1].stencilLoadOp = VK_ATTACHMENT_LOAD_OP_DONT_CARE;
attachments[1].stencilStoreOp = VK_ATTACHMENT_STORE_OP_DONT_CARE;
attachments[1].initialLayout = VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_UNDEFINED;
attachments[1].finalLayout = VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_DEPTH_STENCIL_ATTACHMENT_OPTIMAL;

VkAttachmentReference depthAttachmentRef = {};
depthAttachmentRef.attachment = 1;
depthAttachmentRef.layout = VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_DEPTH_STENCIL_ATTACHMENT_OPTIMAL;

VkSubpassDescription subpass = {};
subpass.pDepthStencilAttachment = &depthAttachmentRef;

renderPassInfo.attachmentCount = static_cast<uint32_t>(attachments.size());
renderPassInfo.pAttachments = attachments.data();
```

**createGraphicsPipelines()**

```
VkPipelineRasterizationStateCreateInfo rasterizer = {};
    rasterizer.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_PIPELINE_RASTERIZATION_STATE_CREATE_INFO;
    rasterizer.depthClampEnable = VK_FALSE;
    rasterizer.rasterizerDiscardEnable = VK_FALSE;
    rasterizer.polygonMode = VK_POLYGON_MODE_FILL;
    rasterizer.lineWidth = 1.0f;
    rasterizer.cullMode = VK_CULL_MODE_NONE;
    rasterizer.frontFace = VK_FRONT_FACE_COUNTER_CLOCKWISE;
    rasterizer.depthBiasEnable = VK_TRUE; // VK_DYNAMIC_STATE_DEPTH_BIAS is set
    rasterizer.flags = 0;

VkPipelineDepthStencilStateCreateInfo depthStencil = {};
    depthStencil.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_PIPELINE_DEPTH_STENCIL_STATE_CREATE_INFO;
    depthStencil.depthTestEnable = VK_TRUE;
    depthStencil.depthWriteEnable = VK_TRUE;
    depthStencil.depthCompareOp = VK_COMPARE_OP_LESS;
    depthStencil.depthBoundsTestEnable = VK_FALSE;
    depthStencil.minDepthBounds = 0.0f;
    depthStencil.maxDepthBounds = 1.0f;
    depthStencil.stencilTestEnable = VK_FALSE;
    depthStencil.front = {};
    depthStencil.back = {};


    VkPipelineColorBlendAttachmentState colorBlendAttachment = {};
    colorBlendAttachment.colorWriteMask = VK_COLOR_COMPONENT_R_BIT | VK_COLOR_COMPONENT_G_BIT | VK_COLOR_COMPONENT_B_BIT | VK_COLOR_COMPONENT_A_BIT;
    colorBlendAttachment.blendEnable = VK_TRUE;
    colorBlendAttachment.srcColorBlendFactor = VK_BLEND_FACTOR_SRC_ALPHA;
    colorBlendAttachment.dstColorBlendFactor = VK_BLEND_FACTOR_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA;
    colorBlendAttachment.colorBlendOp = VK_BLEND_OP_ADD;
    colorBlendAttachment.srcAlphaBlendFactor =  VK_BLEND_FACTOR_ONE;
    colorBlendAttachment.dstAlphaBlendFactor = VK_BLEND_FACTOR_ZERO;
    colorBlendAttachment.alphaBlendOp = VK_BLEND_OP_ADD;

    VkPipelineColorBlendStateCreateInfo colorBlending = {};
    colorBlending.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_PIPELINE_COLOR_BLEND_STATE_CREATE_INFO;
    colorBlending.logicOpEnable = VK_FALSE;
    colorBlending.logicOp = VK_LOGIC_OP_COPY;
    colorBlending.attachmentCount = 1;
    colorBlending.pAttachments = &colorBlendAttachment;
    colorBlending.blendConstants[0] = 0.0f;
    colorBlending.blendConstants[1] = 0.0f;
    colorBlending.blendConstants[2] = 0.0f;
    colorBlending.blendConstants[3] = 0.0f;
```

**createFrameBuffers()**

```
std::array<VkImageView, 2> attachments;
attachments[1] = depthImageView;
...
frameBufferInfo.pAttachments = attachments.data();
```

**drawFrame()**

```
std::array<VkClearValue, 2> clearValues;
clearValues[0].color = {0.25f, 0.25f, 0.5f, 1.0f}; // Purple
clearValues[1].depthStencil = { 1.0f, 0 };

renderPassBeginInfo.clearValueCount = static_cast<uint32_t>(clearValues.size());
renderPassBeginInfo.pClearValues = clearValues.data();
```

**Texture.cpp (Quad vertices/indices)**

```
// Position              // Color RGBA               // UV Map
{{  1.0f,  1.0f, 0.0f }, { 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f }, { 1.0f, 1.0f }},
{{ -1.0f,  1.0f, 0.0f }, { 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f }, { 0.0f, 1.0f }},
{{ -1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f }, { 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f }, { 0.0f, 0.0f }},
{{  1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f }, { 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f }, { 1.0f, 0.0f }}

std::vector<uint32_t> indices = {
        0, 1, 2, 2, 3, 0
    };
```

A couple of notes: The texture is a .ktx loaded by GLI in VK_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM format, and the GLSL shaders are just a basic model view projection matrix and a texture sampler.

Any idea what's causing the textures to ignore other textured quads in the transparent pixels?

Thank you!

Comment: Out of curiosity, why don't you use the Vulkan C++ wrapper?

Comment: @Trass3r Well, I started learning Vulkan a few months ago on vulkan-tutorial.com, which uses vulkan.h instead of the Vulkan-Hpp headers. Not particularly opposed to the C++ wrapper but haven't found any compelling reason to switch over to it so far. Would you say that they're better?

Comment: It depends I guess. They describe their changes in detail at https://github.com/KhronosGroup/Vulkan-Hpp. One other advantage that comes to mind is better auto-completion while coding. But there's probably much more code based on the C API out there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depth test is a common problem when drawing transparent objects. When You draw an object closest to a camera first, it blends with what already is there in a framebuffer. If there is nothing, it blends with a background (clear) color. Next You render an object that is further away. What happens? It fails the depth test because the first object was a quad which wrote data to a depth buffer. And that's why You can also see this "quad" on the second object (as a background color). But You cannot disable the depth test because objects which are drawn later and which are further away, will obscure objects closer to the camera. You either need to:

1. sort objects by their distance from the camera and (in case of transparent objects) draw them in a back to front order, or
2. use a discard() function inside fragment shader for transparent pixels to perform "alpha" test.

Why "normal" objects are rendered in a different way? Probably due to a different depth test/depth write setup and different order of draws.